# EF 6 complex query with Include not including relations

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework, entity-relationship

i have a somewhat complex structure i wont get into,
but what i try doing is:

Get all ShopItems, who's SourceItem has changed,
Get and update them according to their Source/Shop data.

i conjured the following:

```
var query = _ctx.ShopItems
            .Include(si => si.Shop)
            .Include(si=>si.SourceItem)
            .Include(si => si.SourceItem.Source)
            .Include(si=>si.Shop.ShopType)
            .GroupBy(i => i.SourceItem)
            .Where(g => g.Key.LastUpdate > lastUpdate)
            .OrderBy(g => g.Key.LastUpdate)
            .Take(updateCountLimit);
```

the query seems to work, but when itterating the Groups:

`groupItem.Key.Source` is null.

I somewhat solved it by Removing the `Include()`s, saving the Entities to an Array, and explicitly loading the references using 
`_ctx.Entry(updatedSourceItem.Key).Reference(src=>src.Source).Load();`

How can i perform the query i want without round-tripping the DB for explicit loading ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, but it's backwards to start with ShopItems and then group by SourceItem.  Try just starting with SourceItem, something like

```
:

    var query = _ctx.SourceItems
                    .Include(i => i.ShopItems)
                    .Include(i => i.Source)
                    .Include(i => i.ShopItems.Select( si => si.Shop))
                    .Include(i => i.ShopItems.Select( si => si.Shop).ShopType)
                    .Where(i => i.LastUpdate > lastUpdate)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.LastUpdate)
                    .Take(updateCountLimit);
//or 

    var query = _ctx.SourceItems
                    .Include("ShopItems")
                    .Include("Source")
                    .Include("ShopItems.Shops")
                    .Include("ShopItems.Shops.ShopType")
                    .Where(i => i.LastUpdate > lastUpdate)
                    .OrderBy(i => i.LastUpdate)
                    .Take(updateCountLimit);
```

Comment: it does sound logical, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: forgot to check it as the actual solution i used :)